# $p$-divisible groups and Breuil-Kisin modules with coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and residue field $k$. Choose a uniformizer $\pi \in \mathcal{O}_K$ and $E(u)$ be the minimal (Eisenstein) polynomial of $\pi$ over $W(k)$. Let $\varphi \colon W(k)[[u]] \rightarrow W(k)[[u]]$ be the endomorphism that is given by the Witt vector Frobenius on $W(k)$ and that sends $u$ to $u^p$.

It is well known (and due to Breuil and Kisin) that the category of $p$-divisible groups over $\mathcal{O}_K$ is equivalent to the category of finite free $W(k)[[u]]$-modules $M$ endowed with a $\varphi$-semilinear map $\phi\colon M \rightarrow M$ whose ($\varphi$-linearization is such that its) cokernel is killed by $E(u)$.

Now let $R$ be a finite flat $\mathbb{Z}_p$-algebra. I would like to consider $p$-divisible groups $G$ over $\mathcal{O}_K$ endowed with an $R$-action. For such a $G$, the resulting $M$ is automatically an $(R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} W(k))[[u]]$-module. My question is: is $M$ necessarily free as an $(R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} W(k))[[u]]$-module?

My guess is that this may not be true for arbitrary $R$; is it at least true if $R$ is the ring of integers of a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$? More generally, does the $(R \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} W(k))[[u]]$-freeness of $M$ hold if the $p$-adic Tate module $T_p G$ is free as an $R$-module?

Any references that address these questions would be appreciated (I have looked at some articles, but could not find quite what I am asking for).

Comment: Locality of $R$ is necessary to have a change at freeness. You need *some* further hypothesis to have a chance (e.g., to avoid a nonzero element of $R$ acting as 0). So as you suggested, assuming $T_p(G)$ is a free $R$-module is a very reasonable hypothesis to make before posing such a freeness question. You should also use covariant Fontaine-functors or else you'll run into problems when $R$ isn't Gorenstein. Now look at 1.2 in Kisin's paper "Moduli of finite flat group schemes and modularity" (uses covariant functors, since 1.1.7 uses a composition of contravariant functors) for the method.

Comment: Thank you. I agree with what you say, in particular, that I should be careful with variance in order to not run into Gorensteinness issues. I don't see how Kisin's article answers my question though: section 1.2 primarily contains dry semilinear algebra manipulations with little contact with geometry. For instance, the category (Mod FI/$\mathfrak{S}$)$_A$ has freeness baked in through the projectivity assumption in its definition. The only step towards freeness is Lemma 1.2.7 (4), which would give freeness on the level of etale $\varphi$-modules, but how to lift up to $\mathfrak{S}$-modules?